# Partially applying Functions and composing them afterwards

Tags: haskell, composition, chess

I am currently working on a chessgame in Haskell. Here is my function that evaluates to True, when you feed it the right parameters for castling on the kingsside.
(the problem is in part 1 & 2, look at the comments). I tried to use function composition to find a more concise solution, but it didn't really work out for me. I'd be glad if someone could take a glance at what i did and explain where i went wrong ... thanks a lot in advance

```
shortCastlingWhite :: Int -> Int -> GameState -> Bool
shortCastlingWhite start end state@(board,_) = 
(board !! 95 == 10) &&                              -- on 95=(e,1) is a white King
(board !! 98 == 11) &&                              -- on 98=(h,8) is a white Rook
(start == 95 && end == 97) &&                       -- move from (e,1) to 97=(g,1)
(not $ (wasMoved state 95 || wasMoved state 98) &&  -- King and Tower weren't moved until now
(not $ (indexOccupied 96 state ||                       -- part 1 !! 96=(f,1) and (g,1) are unoccupied
(indexOccupied 97 state) ||                         -- part 1
(isThreatenedBy Black 95 state) ||                  -- part 2 !! neither (e,1) nor (f,1) or (g,1) are threatened by Black Figures
(isThreatenedBy Black 96 state) ||                  -- part 2
(isThreatenedBy Black 97 state)))                   -- part 2
```

here are the typesignatures for the used functions

```
isThreatenedBy :: Colour -> GameState -> Int -> Bool
wasMoved :: GameState -> Int -> Bool
```

i wanted to rewrite the very verbose parts 1 and 2 as :

```
all (swap indexUnoccupied state) [96,97] && 
(all ((not.isThreatenedBy) Black state) [95,96,97]) && 
(all ((not.wasMoved) state) [95,98])  
    where swap f a b = f b a
--
```

but i cant get around the errormessage of :

```
newchess.hs:240:181:
    Couldn't match expected type `GameState -> a0 -> Bool`
                with actual type `Bool`
    The function `not . isThreatenedBy` is applied to two arguments,
    but its type `Colour -> Bool` has only one
    In the first argument of `all`, namely
      `((not . isThreatenedBy) Black state)`
    In the first argument of `(&&)', namely
    `(all ((not . isThreatenedBy) Black state) [95, 96, 97])`
```

isThreatenedBy :: Colour -> GameState -> Int -> Bool

when i compose not and isThreatenedBy i should get 
a function `f = (not . isThreatenedBy)` of type

`f :: Colour -> GameState -> Int -> Bool`

but really i get something like `Colour -> Bool` i think.
Then i partially apply it with values of Colour and GameState
and the resulting function f' should be of type

`f' :: Int -> Bool`

and then i kinda map it over the list `[95,96,97]` and see 
if every element satisfies `f'` via `all`

or so was the plan ...

```
newchess.hs:240:186:
    Couldn't match type `GameState -> Int -> Bool` with `Bool`
    Expected type: Colour -> Bool
      Actual type: Colour -> GameState -> Int -> Bool
    Probable cause: `isThreatenedBy` is applied to too few arguments
    In the second argument of `(.)`, namely `isThreatenedBy`
    In the expression: not . isThreatenedBy
```

its odd that (not . wasMoved) is applied to too many arguments in error1 
and probably to too few in error 2 , but
i cant move the list elements inside the brackets , 
otherwise i could just go back to the point from that i started

```
newchess.hs:240:238:
    Couldn't match expected type `a1 -> Bool` with actual type `Bool`
    Possible cause: `not . wasMoved` is applied to too many arguments
    In the first argument of `all`, namely `((not . wasMoved) state)`
    In the second argument of `(&&)`, namely
      `(all ((not . wasMoved) state) [95, 98])`
```

same as above in error 1 (just this time with wasMoved)

```
newchess.hs:240:243:
    Couldn't match type `Int -> Bool' with `Bool`
    Expected type: GameState -> Bool
      Actual type: GameState -> Int -> Bool
    Probable cause: `wasMoved` is applied to too few arguments
    In the second argument of `(.)`, namely `wasMoved`
    In the expression: not . wasMoved
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

as in error 2 i think

Comment: Note that what you call `swap` is already provided as the `flip` function.

Comment: The name `swap` is also "taken" for `swap :: (a,b) -> (b,a)` in `Data.Tuple`.

Comment: thanks to both of you , i didn't know that ... but i will keep it in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might have misunderstood this one a bit, but have a look at this. This does NOT work:

```
Prelude> let f = (abs . (+))

<interactive>:11:5:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> a)
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that ‘f’ has the inferred type
      f :: forall a. (Num a, Num (a -> a)) => a -> a -> a
```

It does not type check. The reason for this is the fact that the `(.)` function takes two functions as parameters, where those two functions take one parameter each. In this example the `(+)` function takes two parameters and is thus of the wrong type. This works:

```
Prelude> let f = (abs . (+ 3))
```

Because I turned the function into a function that takes only one parameter. Your `isThreatenedBy` function could be changed the same way:

```
(all (not . (isThreatenedBy Black state)) [95,96,97])
```

Not sure if that was really you root problem, but try it out.

Comment: Note also that `f . g` is equivalent to `\x -> f ( g x)`. You *could* (but **shouldn't**) use `(.) . (.) $ f g` to obtain the equivalent of `\x y -> f (g x y)` or even `((.) . (.)) . (.) $ f g` to get `\x y z -> f (g x y z)`.  So using `((.).(.)).(.)$ not isThreatenedBy` should work and what was intended... though avoid this trickery.

Comment: it works perfectly , and now i do realize what i did wrong 
i wasn't even partially applying `isThreatendBy` correctly 
because i put it in brackets wich cutted the application off ...

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with the custom predicate:

```
isThreatenedBy :: Colour -> State -> Position -> Bool
```

We can of course write that as such:

```
isThreatenedBy :: Colour -> (State -> (Position -> Bool))
```

Now, it should be clear why this function can't be composed with `not`, which itself is `Bool -> Bool`:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

now subsituting:

```
:: not . isThreatenedBy

-- from `not`:
b ~ Bool
c ~ Bool 

-- from `isThreatenedBy:
a ~ Colour
b ~ (State -> (Position -> Bool))
```

Clearly `b`s don't match here.

---

Now what you can do is either push the composition outside the first application (what dvaergiller did in his answer), or introduce additional step:

```
all . map not . map (isThreatenedBy color state) $ [95,96,97]
```

This might contrast the typical map-reduce pattern, but I personally think it's a bit more readable.

---

Alternatively, a helper of:

```
none = and . map not
```

(Or, as suggested by @FrerichRaabe and generously provided by Augustus De Morgan):

```
none = not . or
```

Could make this even clearer.

Comment: isn't `map f . map g = map (f . g)` wouldn't that make things easier?

Comment: I actually like this answer more than mine.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe this is what the other answer already mentions. I present it as an alternative, and frankly, I'd probably write the `none` helper myself.

Comment: `all id` is just `and`.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe oops, you're right. I tend to forget about that. I tend to write `foldl1 (&&)` because that doesn't make me remember that difference -.-.

Comment: An even more concise definition of `none` is `not . or`.

Comment: thank you for your precise and good answer , i think i'm even going to define a `none` like you did , because its very concise and readable
but still im choosing dvaergillers answer , because it was easier for me to realize what i did wrong while reading his answer .
nevertheless thank you for the great answer =)